# Where is the Twiml xml for my application stored?

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I have inherited a call center php application using twillio webrtc, and the twilio api.The trouble I'm having is the application, only makes a call to one number. I've looked through the controller using Twiml and Voice Response, and as far as I can tell a phone number gets passed from the front-end and `$to_number` is assigned that value.I've changed this value a million times , and it still dials the same number. It's because of this that I think that in my actual Twiml, is where it may be reset. The trouble is I can't find any Twiml in the entire application. I've also checked on twilio for any Twiml in my apps, and this is all I found. [Twiml app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niIC4.png)  When I try making a call using the call button, and an error is thrown.

I've been succesful in making calls to different numbers using the following request [post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i85XH.png)

In short, where is my Twiml (in xml) stored? Any ideas what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TwiML Application SID is passed in the [Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) to the client. The TwiML Application has set of URL's, one being the Voice URL, that points to TwiML which tells Twilio what to do.

If the Access Token is being sent to the console log, you can decode it to find the Application SID ([to lookup in Twilio Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/apps)) [here](https://jwt.io/). You can enable client side debug [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025738593-Enable-Debugging-with-Twilio-Client).